# what is "spark.history.retainedApplications" points to

Tags: apache-spark

As per apache doc "http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html"

spark.history.retainedApplications points to "The number of application UIs to retain. If this cap is exceeded, then the oldest applications will be removed"

But I see more than configured apps into the UI. Is it correct or it stores those many apps into memory only or load again into memory when needed. Please clarify. Thx

Comment: Have you set this value to something other than the default?

Comment: I've set it to 100, but i'm seeing 200+ application displaying on the UI, excluding the incomplete ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That setting specifically applies to the history server. If you don't have one started (it's typically used with YARN and Mesos I believe), then the setting you're after is `spark.ui.retainedJobs`. Check the [Spark UI configuration parameters](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-ui) for more details.

These settings only apply to jobs, so in order to pass them to the master itself, check the `spark.deploy` options in the [stand-alone deployment section](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts). You can set them via the `SPARK_MASTER_OPTS` environment variable.

If you want to clean the data files produced by workers, check the `spark.worker.cleanup` options in the same section. You can set them via the `SPARK_WORKER_OPTS` environment variable on your workers.

Comment: Thanks Marius. Also is there any property which I can specify that controls how many application logs should be stored in the hdfs for spark. If I define 200, then it should automatically delete older ones and maintain only 200 at any give point.

Comment: Nice, just one confirmation. It works with yarn, right?
In apache doc(http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html), it is mentioned this works only in standalone mode only, not yarn.
spark.worker.cleanup.enabled false Enable periodic cleanup of worker / application directories. Note that this only affects standalone mode, as YARN works differently.

Comment: Yeah that's specific to stand-alone, for YARN cleanup I guess you should refer to the YARN docs.